# How to launch a shell command on an already opened specific terminal?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a script `./runStart.sh` that creates a new xterm and in this xterm launch the `script run.log` command.
Then, to finish the process I launch a script `./runStop.sh` that kills the xterm and do other stuff behind.
The problem I have is that as I kill the process while running, there is no `exit` call, so the `script` command does not save the data in the actual file.

Do you know how I could launch a command in the second script `./runStop.sh` that makes this `exit` call instead of the `kill <pid>` command ?

Comment: Why not add a trap that will shut it down properly?

Comment: I checked out how trap works, but I still don't know how to send a signal to another terminal. Is there a command for this ? Does it work with the pid ?

Comment: You send the signal to the shell running the script. `kill` can be used to send signals.

Comment: You may want to try using a `kill -HUP` command, this sends a "hangup" signal to the process, which should be catchable by a `trap` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `bash` builtin `trap` to catch a signal (except `KILL` and `STOP`) and do the required cleanup.

For example, here i am catching the pseudo signal `EXIT` that would cover any signal that would make the shell to exit:

```
xterm -e '/bin/bash' -c 'trap "echo ok >/tmp/foobar" EXIT; sleep 5'
```

`sleep 5` is my main task and `echo ok >/tmp/foobar` is cleanup task upon exiting.

Alternately if are sure about the signal to be sent/received e.g. `HUP`, `INT`, you can trap those directly.